# Layoutparams set weight in code

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

Hi I crated TableLayout in XML
Now In code i refer to tablelayout by finViewById. Then i create dynamically new TableRow(row2) which are contain four child(it happends when i click dodaj_wiersz Button). Textv1,Editt1, Textv2, Editt2

My questions is, how can i set evenly weight for row, like after use "distibute weights evenly" button in XML.

My code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.nowe_sciany);

        final TableLayout tablayout=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.wyglad);

        //reakcja na dodaj wiersz
        final Button dodaj_wiersz=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addrow);
        dodaj_wiersz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                TableRow row2 = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

                textv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                textv2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                editt1 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                editt2 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                textv1.setText("width: ");
                textv2.setText("height: ");

                row2.addView(textv1);
                row2.addView(editt1);
                row2.addView(textv2);
                row2.addView(editt2);

                tablayout.addView(row2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams());                            
            }           
        });         
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the weight on the layoutparams like this:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
```

The params are width, height and weight.

Then you can set the params to the views:

```
textv1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: If i try this the this is an error The constructor TableRow(int, int, float) is undefined

Comment: My bad, typo in code (should be TableRow.LayoutParams). Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have fixed 4 view (Textv1,Editt1, Textv2, Editt2) in the TableRow then you can define TableLayout like this:

```
TableRow.layoutParams trLayout = 
                    new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.25f);
tablayout.addView(row2, trLayout);
```

> To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to "0dp" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view to "0dp" (for a horizontal layout).

LinearLayout is Parent of TableRowLayout [#doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: In XML i crate only TableLayout so i can't set "android:layout_height of each view to "0dp" ". It's basic example, because i have to create 2x row. So i cant crate LinearLayout in xml.

Comment: Nope, I've just mention this as I've used `0` in my answer. BTW is your problem solved.